# How can I create several javascript image buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am new at creating websites in HTML. I use free for all SeaMonkey software. So, I want to create several image buttons which would change when user moves the mouse over the image. I already have created 3 images for the different stages of each button (normal, active and clicked). I wrote this code for the first button:

```
<body>
    <a href="first.html" onmouseover="return changeImage(jsbutton)" onmouseout="return changeImageBack(jsbutton)">
        <img name="jsbutton" src="first normal.png" alt="first">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function changeImage() {
                document.images["jsbutton"].src= "first active.png";
                return true;
            }
            function changeImageBack() {
                document.images["jsbutton"].src = "first normal.png";
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </a>
</body>
```

And it works. But when I did the same for second button, it didn't work and in addition to that, the first one has stopped working too. What do I have to change to make it work properly?

**Update:**

For second button I wrote:

```
<a href="second.html" onmouseover="return changeImage(jsbutton)"
onmouseout="return changeImageBack(jsbutton)">
<img name="jsbutton" src="second normal.png" alt="second">
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImage()
{
document.images["jsbutton"].src= "second active.png";
return true;
}
function changeImageBack()
{
document.images["jsbutton"].src = "second normal.png";
return true;
}
</script> </a>
</body>
```

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle? that would help

Comment: Why didn't you use css-`:hover`?

Comment: If not a jsfiddle, can you please post exactly how you did the same for second button..? are you sure the first one worked? cause when i checked  `first%20normal.png` and `first normal.png` is not the same.. I'd suggest using an image name without spaces..

Comment: @jp310 I don't have it

Comment: @TJ I wrote `first normal.jpg` but when I closed it and opened again SeaMonkey changed it by itself to `first%20normal.png`

Comment: That's because when you `open` or `refresh` your page is rendered again, where you have written "first%20normal.png" manually. javascript won't add the `%20` for you as far as i can see..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can also use inline javascript for this purpose as it is pretty simple:

```
<a href="first.html" >
    <img onmouseover="this.src = 'second active.png'; " src="second normal.png" onmouseout="this.src = 'second normal.png'; "  alt="first" />
</a>
```

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Waa4H/) , in which I used some random images urls

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript is failing because you are using the same name attribute for both images. Each element must have a unique name.

That being said, the functionality you are after is already built in to CSS, so unless you have a specific requirement for this to be JavaScript, this is a problem far better solved in CSS, using :hover.

So in your html:

```
<a href="first.html" id="firstButton"></a>
```

In your CSS:

```
#firstButton {
  background-image: url('first normal.png');
  display:block;
  height: [height of img];
  width: [width of img];
}
#firstButton:visited {background-image: url('first visited.png'); }
#firstButton:hover { background-image: url('first active.png'); }
```

And you are done! No use recreating functionality already built in to CSS!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same "`name`" attribute i.e. `jsbutton` for the both the images. Use different name attributes. Also css `:hover` is a better way to do this problem.